# hasMany Relation Laravel - Not getting query result

Tags: laravel

I have a post with multiple images. But I want to only fetch images with PNG format.
So I do this is post :

```
 public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ImagesModel','mapID','id');
    }

    public function oftype($query)
    {
        return
        $query->where('type', '=', 'PNG');
    }
```

But this is not working.

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$post->images()->oftype()->get();
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Add laravel version in tags please

Answer (score 2):

For that to work you need to use [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes)

```
public function scopeType($query)
{
    return $query->where('type', '=', 'PNG');
}
```

Then use as

```
$post->images()->type()->get()
```

Comment: Call to undefined method IlluminateDatabaseQueryBuilder::type()

Comment: @kirobo can you paste the full error? There is no method for type() it is ofType()

Comment: Yes. Same. I did this in try catch block and this is the error I get.

Comment: Call to undefined method IlluminateDatabaseQueryBuilder::type()

Comment: Where in the code, what line, what else does the error say, I don't believe that my fix is related to that error.

Comment: Try to get posts with image like this one, Post::with('images')->oftype()->find($id);